# multiple while loop with 2 momentary switches

Tags: python

I have two switches that need to turn off each motor independently then once both are off turn off the motor controller. all three while loops need to run at the same time. 
Not sure how I should go about getting this to work. I have tried threading but have not got that to work. Hopefully it is something easy i am missing. pretty new to python.

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from multiprocessing import Process
# set mode
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
# setup
# enableA
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
# enableb
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)
# enable INT1
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
# enable INT4
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)
# enable Switch Down sensor Left
GPIO.setup(32, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
# enable Switch Down sensor Right
GPIO.setup(33, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
# turn on ena, enb
GPIO.output(11, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(15, GPIO.HIGH)
# Turn two motor Down
GPIO.output(7, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(16, GPIO.HIGH)
# turn off left motor
def MLO():
    while True:
        input_state = GPIO.input(32)
        if not input_state:
            print('Left off')
            GPIO.output(7, GPIO.LOW)
# turn off right motor
def MRO():
    while True:
        input_Rswitch = GPIO.input(33)
        if not input_Rswitch:
            print('Right off')
            GPIO.output(16, GPIO.LOW)
# turn off motor control
def RCO():
    while True:
        input_state2 = GPIO.input(33) or GPIO.input(32)
        if not input_state2:
            print ('system off')
            GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(15, GPIO.LOW)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=MLO())
    p2 = Process(target=MRO())
    p3 = Process(target=RCO())
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
GPIO.cleanup()
exit()
```

Comment: You don't need those functions, add the `while True:` in your `main()`, follow by a `if: ... elif: ... else: ...` condition checking. You don't need Process either unless there are process running. You probably need to have some sleep() function otherwise the motor will be turn off almost immediately after being turn on.

Comment: BTW, it is better for you to ask Raspberry Pi related programming questions at [Rapsberry Pi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Got it figured out now.
Also was not aware of the rasberrypi subdomain. will head there with raspi questions now.